# in styles not working value of State in the ternary operator

Tags: react-native

please tell me why the ternary operator does not take the value from state in StyleSheet

in input styles, the ternary operator does not understand the value from the state

at textinput focus, the value of the state becomes true, when changing, I want to change the styles, how else can this be realized

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    FlatList,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

export default class Chat extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            text: '',
            sendButtonVisible: false
        };
    }
    sendMessage = () => {
        let message = this.state.text;
        if (message != '') {    
            this.state.items.push({
                key: message,
                dateTime: this.dateTime()
            });
            this.setState({
                items: [...this.state.items],
                text: ''
            });
        }
    }
    dateTime = () => {
        let date = new Date();
        addZero = (num) => {
            if(num >= 0 && num < 10) {
                return `0${num}`;
            }
            return num;
        }
        let dateTime = `${addZero(date.getHours())}:${addZero(date.getMinutes())}`;
        return(dateTime);
    }
    sendButtonVisible = () => {
        if (this.state.sendButtonVisible) {
            return(
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendButton} onPress={this.sendMessage}>
                    <Icon name='send' color='rgb(255, 255, 255)' size={25} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.flatListBox}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.items}
                        renderItem={({item}) => 
                            <View style={styles.messageBlock}>
                                <Text style={styles.message}>
                                    {item.key}
                                    <Text style={{fontSize: 10}}>{item.dateTime}</Text>
                                </Text>
                            </View>                     
                        }
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputBox}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                        onFocus={() => this.setState({sendButtonVisible: true})}
                        onBlur={() => this.setState({sendButtonVisible: false})}
                        placeholder='Write a message'
                    />
                    {this.sendButtonVisible()}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
    },
    inputBox: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        margin: 10
    },
    input: {
        flex: 6,
        borderColor: 'rgb(227, 227, 227)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(227, 227, 227)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        //borderTopRightRadius: (this.state.sendButtonVisible) ? 0 : 10,
        //borderBottomRightRadius: (this.state.sendButtonVisible) ? 0 : 10,
        fontSize: 16,
        paddingLeft: 15
    },
    sendButton: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 206, 209)',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderTopRightRadius: 10,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 10
    },
    flatListBox: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        margin: 10
    },
    messageBlock: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        marginTop: 2,
    },
    message: {
        fontSize: 16,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 206, 209)',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingBottom: 6,
        paddingTop: 4,
        borderRadius: 15,
        color: '#fff'
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGOu1.png)

Comment: can you share some code of this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro `this` points to the current class and you are writing the styles const out of the class scope that's the reason it cannot find `this.state.sendButtonVisible`

you can only use this in the scope of the class. If you want to use it then move it inside the class